# All moments of the Standard Gaussian Distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

I have to compute all moments of the Standard Normal Distribution using any of the following properties of the $\Gamma$-function:

1. $\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt(\pi)$
2. For all $s>0: \Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$
3. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}: \Gamma(n+1)=n!$
4. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}: \Gamma\left(n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{(2n)!\sqrt(\pi)}{4^nn!}$

**What I have done so far:**
I let $X$ be a Gaussian-distribuated random variable. Then we have the Standard Normal Distribution
$$
\rho(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
$$
such that all moments of the Standard Normal Distribution can be described with
$$
\mathbb{E}X^k=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^k\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^ke^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx
$$
I try to rewrite this to a form that allows me to use the following definition of the $\Gamma$-function
$$
\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx
$$
If $k$ is even then
$$
\mathbb{E}X^k =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^ke^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ke^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx
$$
Then I get stuck here. I don't know how to go on from here. Am I doing something completely wrong? Or am I on right track?

Comment: try substituting variables. You want a $e^{-x}$, soooo

Comment: @Exodd Can you elaborate on how? I have tried using intergration by substitution, as well as integration by parts. However, none of these methods seem to yield any useful results for me.

Comment: as Exodd said, you want $e^{-x}$, but you have $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. So maybe substitution $y = \frac{x^2}{2}$ can help?